# develop Web sites for mobiles

Tags: mobile

I want to implement "mobile website provider" tool. Basically, It intake desktop website url and generate a mobile version of website without edit/add additional content to the desktop website. I am planning to design a product like (what [mofuse.com](http://www.mofuse.com) does. This website create mobile websites). This tool should be hassle free to client(who are not tech savvy.)

1.Q) I want to know kind of functionality involved in this process.

2.Q) In Java Technology, I need the tool set and functionality of this actitity.

As I am new to this mobile application environment. Any information(web links) regarding this will be appreciated.

#### Update:

its not like skweezer.com.

I had a website and I want to "mobile"ize it. 1) What kind of java tool set I have to use to create mobile web site? 2) How to test in multiple mobile devices 3) How the domain name will be created for mobile websites.

Comment: Edit your question if you have more information.  Don't leave answers that aren't answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out our Wapple Architect tech (http://wapple.net) - we allow you to use the same content from web to mobile, but if it's mobile, instead of outputting the html, use a web service to turn it into the right content for that particular handset.

Mobilizes the same domain, no need for m.yourdomain.com or anything like that.

Check http://wapple.net on a mobile for example!

Answer (score 0):

there are certain plugins which mobilise your website .
they check user agent and if user agent is of mobile browser they load another css of mobile and if you want to redirect some another redirect it ther.

you dont have to buy separate domain make sub domain  or cname like

m.yourdomain.ccom
wap.yaourdomain.com

try some javacripts code which detect browser type and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn about mobile toolkits are

WURFL - The open source community built around profiling devices and managing their capabilities (http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

Mobile Elements - A tool to help you build mobile sites using a proxy type approach (http://www.mobilelements.com)

Device Atlas - A device profiling tool (http://www.deviceatlas.com)